# How to do sign out from MSAL authentication.?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal

I am working on xamarin forms where I am using MSAL for authentication to authenticate. Now I want to sign out the user once he clicks on the sign-out. For sign out, I wrote Below code

```
 foreach (var user in await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync())
   {
      await App.PCA.RemoveAsync(user);
   }
```

The above code is executing without any problem but when I again try to log in it is not asking for the password. I am clearing the cookies from the app using dependency service like

created one interface in xamarin forms project

```
public interface IAuthentication
{
    void ClearAllCookies();
}
```

And in the android project providing the implementation for the interface

```
 public void ClearAllCookies()
{
    CookieManager.Instance.RemoveSessionCookie();
    CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
}
```

I am doing Authentication like below

In App.xamal.cs file

```
    public static IPublicClientApplication PCA = null;
    public static string ClientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };

    public App()
    {   
        PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{ClientID}://auth")
            .Build();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //On login button click
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

    try
    {
        IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
        authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                          .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
    {
        try
        {
            authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                      .WithLoginHint(EmailId) //Here I am passing Email Id
                                      .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                      .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Acquire token interactive failed. See exception message for details: ", ex2.Message, "Dismiss");
        }
    }
    if (authResult != null)
    {
        var content = await GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Dashboard.PartnerDashboard(content));                        
    }
}
```

After clearing again it is not asking for the password. If I uninstall and reinstall the app also it is not asking for the password. How to resolve this?

Comment: What version of the MSAL library are you using?

Comment: @FreakyAli. 4.7 version

Comment: I am using 4.4 and i have never faced an issue!

Comment: I tried with 4.4 and 4.3 but no change in result.

Comment: Umm, When you say not asking for the password, then, in that case, you have two different pages for username and password? And when I say pages I mean in the webview!!!

Comment: @FreakyAli Only One time it asked for the password. First, only one textbox was there once I enter the email then textbox for password shown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code for clearing accounts in MSAL.

```
public void ClearAllCookies(string authority)
{
  var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
  authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
  CookieManager.Instance.RemoveSessionCookie();
  CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
}
```

where authority = "https://login.windows.net/common";

Try below code before authenticate code running, for removing old accounts.

```
   var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
   if(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
   {
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority,false, null); 
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and I tried with your code but the same problem is repeating.

Comment: Ok. Can you please show me your authenticate code once. I will check.

Comment: I have added authentication code in the question Please go through.

Comment: It's not going inside if condition only.